# datetimepicker does not appear for dynamically created field in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am creating an input field dynamically to display the datetimepicker.when i create the field in the body and give class='datetimepicker' then it display the datepicker in the app but when tried to create a field dynamically and give class name datetimepicker it doesnot display the datepicker can any one tell me whats the issue.
here is code for date time picker:

```
var input_date=$(document.createElement('input')).attr('id','brthdate');
    input_date.attr('class','datetimepicker');
    input_date.attr('onclick','displaydate()');
    input_date.attr('type','text');
    input_date.appendTo('#contentDemo');
$('#demopage').trigger('create');
function displaydate(){
$("#brthdate").datetimepicker();}
```

here is the list of js files used for datetimepicker:

```
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" 
mobiscroll.css" 
jquery.js jquery-ui.js
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js 
jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js 
mobiscroll.js
application.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
var input_date=$(document.createElement('input')).attr('id','brthdate');
input_date.attr('class','datetimepicker');

//input_date.attr('onclick','displaydate()');
$("#brthdate").datetimepicker();

input_date.attr('type','text');
input_date.appendTo('#contentDemo');
$('#demopage').trigger('create');
```

Or just directly use its class name on `DOM READY` like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
});
```

And then create the new element

Comment: I tried as you said but till nothing happen its not showing datetimepicker

Comment: Is it creating input field..??

Comment: yes it is creating the input field i check it in the browser firefox using firebug

Comment: Try with my second ans also

Comment: Still its acting same

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below code.

```
var input_date=$('<input/>').attr('id','brthdate');
    input_date.attr('class','datetimepicker');
    input_date.datetimepicker();
    input_date.attr('type','text');
    input_date.appendTo('#contentDemo');
$('#demopage').trigger('create');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H2tXZ/6/)**

Comment: In your code when you click first time it will create datetimepicker and to see it in action you need to click on it again....so nitialize it on creating time so when user first click on field they will see the datetimepicker.

Comment: still its acting same

Comment: @NeeravShah what about datetimepicker css..?? have you included it..??? see my demo...i have added css for that

Comment: Ok but when i try to create the static field in the div it doesn't require the timepicker.css.

Comment: its showing an error in the logcat 08-24 07:20:34.604: E/Web Console(3050): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-ui.js:8753

Comment: Is there any other way to show the date selector in android bcz after replacing the jquery-ui with the jquery-ui-1.9.1.min.js its showing an error 08-24 08:37:48.884: E/Web Console(3994): Uncaught Error: no such method 'value' for slider widget instance at file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.js:507